# Como fazer numa mesma chamada POST do tipo @Multipart enviando uma imagem, campos de String e também um Array de objetos?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, retrofit

Em uma chamada, eu faço o cadastro de um profissional, que envolve o envio do seu `avatar`, que aparece na primeira linha como `file` e também faço o envio de outros atributos do profissional, como por exemplo, o local que ele trabalha.

Este local também está salvo no banco de dados, e possui um ID específico, por tanto, o objeto `local` possui **nome** e **id**.

Enviar strings como `@Part` é fácil, não tive problemas. Enviar uma string de objetos `local`, no entanto, está desafiador.

Alguém consegue me ajudar a solucionar isso?

> PS. O código está em Kotlin.

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("/profissional")
    fun postProfissional(
        @Part file : MultipartBody.Part,
        @Part("name") name: RequestBody,
        @Part("tempoPro") tempoPro: RequestBody,
        @Part("address") address: RequestBody,
        @Part("addressNumb") addressNumb: RequestBody,
        @Part("city") city: RequestBody,
        @Part("state") state: RequestBody,
        @Part("cep") cep: RequestBody,
        @Part("birthDate") birthDate: RequestBody,
        @Part("email") email: RequestBody,
        @Part("pass") pass: RequestBody,
        @Part("phone") phone: RequestBody,
        @Part("Local") saloesQueAtua: ArrayList<Local>?,
        @Part("services") services: ArrayList<RequestBody>?
    ): Call<ResponseBody>
```

Classe Local:

```
class Local(
    var id : String?,
    var salao : String?
)
```

Comment: Não ficou claro qual é o problema. Está dando algum erro quando vc faz essa requisição?

Comment: Erro não, ele compila e aceita a requisição... mas **não** o campo "saloesQueAtua" não contém nada... é encaminhado como contendo apenas {}.
De que maneira você enviaria uma imagem juntamente com outros campos, sendo que um deles é um array de objectcs?

Comment: Converte tudo para Base64 e converte do outro lado